# Is included in use case read as for each time or one time?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

So, I have designed a use case diagram. But im having a confusion about the use of included. It is regarding a student management system. A student can register for a module only if he has enrolled in a course. The issue is that if I put included from register to enrol, will it imply that every time he registers, he will have to enrol? Also,  what does 2 included coming out from a use case mean, is it either or or both needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusions between use cases are done unconditionally, so if *UC* includes *UC*<sub>1</sub> and includes *UC*<sub>2</sub> and ... and includes *UC*<sub>n</sub> than means each time *UC* is activated then *UC*<sub>1</sub> and *UC*<sub>2</sub> and ... and *UC*<sub>n</sub> are done too, whatever their number *n*. The inclusions are not exclusive between them.

> if I put included from register to enrol, will it imply that every time he registers, he will have to enrol?

yes, this is the case where *n* is 1

> what does 2 included coming out from a use case mean, is it either or or both needed?

both, this is the case where *n* is 2

---

If you want something conditional use an *extension* but warning the arrow is drawn in the opposite direction, rather than to have `UC1- - -<<include>>- - -> UC2` (*UC1* includes *UC2*) we have `UC1<- - -<<extend>>- - -UC2` (*UC2* extends *UC1*)

---

> to make things clearer. Make as if I have a purchase use case and i can only purchase if a create account use case or login account use case exist. How do i represent that?

For me the best way to model that is to use a precondition. So to be able to activate the UC 'purchase' the precondition is to be logged (and to be logged the precondition is an account was created).

A use case is not only an ellipse in a diagram, a use case must have a description and that description indicates when they exist the pre and post conditions.

Comment: to make things clearer. Make as if I have a purchase use case and i can only purchase if a create account use case or login account use case exist. How do i represent that?

Comment: @ox1234567 I am sure I already answer to your remark through a remark yesterday, but it strangely disappeared. So I redo editing my answer (to have a trace if someone edit my answer).

Comment: very strange things happens on S.O., why my remark to answer to ox1234567 disappeared ? why that answer and the one of qwerty_so was DV (silently as usual) ?